# Wpf application bulk installation

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i have folder with multiple programs .exe inside  inside and i would like to make a button once clicked it will start all installations but it has to wait for one to be over in order to start another.

I also need cancel button which will stop the processes.

I need to make this in wpf.

Tried using checkboxes but once all checked and button clicked only one installation starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if you are running a bunch of installations an want to run them in order, I would setup a `Task.Factory` or `BackgroundWorker` so you are not blocking then UI thread. I would also make sure you are using MVVM for all this to make it easier.

I would start by setting up a helper class for the installs. If doing MVVM this class would obviously be setup differently.

```
public class Programs
{
    public string InstallName = "";
    public string InstallPath = "";
    public bool ExecuteInstall = false;
    public int InstallProcessID = 0;
}
```

Then setup a collection of these and mark them to run or not based on your checkboxes. With MVVM, you can bind the executeInstall directly to a checkbox.

Then a function that does work and is called by a separate thread. The key to this is with the calling and how you use Process

```
        try
        {
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = <Your program collection object>.InstallPath;
                myProcess.Start();
                <Your program collection object>.InstallProcessID = myProcess.Id;
                myProcess.WaitForExit();

                // Any follow up code after install has completed.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error message that uses ex
        }
```

Cancel button can look for a process ID and then kill that process. You can also create a temporary int var to store the current process ID of the installing application instead of having it set something in the collection.

So that is the general idea. I recommend studying up more on program design though as stackoverflow is more of a specific place for questions and not how to write something.